# VBS naming a zipfile?

Tags: windows, vbscript, zip, unzip

Im trying to create a blank zip file using VBScript. But using just the `CreateTextFile` method created an error file which does not open. Tried adding

```
Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)
```

and

```
write("PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))
```

Both seems to work. I couldn't figure out why this is used. Could someone explain me this command?

Answer (score 2):

[Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) files can contain text files, but they aren't textfiles themselves, so just creating an empty text file with the extension .zip naturally isn't going to work.

Your two `Write` statements both create the byte sequence of an empty zip file. That's why the resulting file can be opened as a zip file.